# Assert if class exists by name inside a file with a given path

Tags: python, unit-testing

In a python project I'm working on I have a file structure with code and unit tests together (cannot be changed) and I created a separate test/data folder to keep all the data files needed for the unit tests, in order to keep it clean.

In order to keep things organised, I'm replicating in test/data the same structure used in src, plus a folder level for each test file, each class inside it and each test method inside it.

In the end, if `src` has

```
src
 | module_a
 | module_b
   | sub_module_c
     | some_test_file.py
```

and `some_test_file.py` has

```
class SomeTestClass(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_something(self):
    some_json_dict = get_json("some_json_dict.json")
```

then `test/data` will have

```
test/data
 | module_a
 | module_b
   | sub_module_c
     | some_test_file
       | some_test_class
         | test_something
           | some_json_dict.json
```

Because assuring this structure is maintained (it's a shared project) might not be easy, I'm creating a unit test that asserts if the whole structure in test/data is valid, i.e. asserting that:

- file `src/module_b/sub_module_c/some_test_file.py` exists
- class `SomeTestClass` exists inside that file
- method `test_something` exists in that class

I've managed to achieve the first point (with much appreciated help got here), with this

```py
for directory, child_directories, child_files in walk(test_data_base_path):
    if not child_directories and not child_files:
        self.fail("Directory {} is empty".format(directory))
    # if we are in a "leaf" level
    if child_files:
        test_data_file_name = path.abspath(path.join(directory, pardir, pardir))
        test_file = path.join(code_base_path, path.relpath(test_data_file_name, test_data_base_path)) + ".py"
        self.assertTrue(path.exists(test_file))

        # TODO: also check if the class exists
        class_name = "..."
        # TODO: also check if the test exists
        test_name = "..."
```

but I'm having trouble asserting the other 2 requirements.

**TL;DR**

I need a way to, given a class name (str) and a file path name (str), assert if the class exists in that file;
and, given a method name (str) assert if the method exists in the same class.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation I managed to get what I needed. Here's the piece of code that achieved it:

```py
# assert the class exists
module = importlib.import_module(package)
try:
    the_class = getattr(module, class_name)
except AttributeError:
    self.fail("...")

# assert the test exists
if test_name not in dir(the_class):
    self.fail("...")
```